# Dashboard into StackPanel

Tags: google-apps-script, dashboard, stackpanel

I am getting a 'Object Type doesn't match Column Type' error and not sure why... not sure if its something wrong in my code (more than likely) or if it just won't accept the dashboard. I am thinking that my error has to do with the Data Source and how I'm pulling the data from the spreadsheet.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('DHS: Kurzweil Calendar');

  //Create stack panel
  var stackPanel = app.createStackPanel().setSize('100%', '100%');
  var info = about(app);
  var p1 = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vrtPanel1').add(info);
  var cal = calendar(app);
  var p2 = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vrtPanel2').add(cal);
  var form = formBuild(app);
  var p3 = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vrtPanel3').add(form);

  //add widgets to each stack panel, and name the stack panel
  stackPanel.add(p1, 'About the Lab');
  stackPanel.add(p2, 'Lab Calendar');
  stackPanel.add(p3, 'Lab Scheduling');

  //Add the panel to the application
  app.add(stackPanel);
  return app;
}

function about(app){
  return app.createHTML('<br />' + 
                        '<p>The Kurzweil Lab at Davie High School supports <i>20 independent student workstations</i> and is designed for the specific use of Kurzweil software.  The lab\'s main objective is to support students who have a Read-Aloud accommodation on their Individual Education Plan (IEP).  If a student does not have a Read-Aloud accommodation, but has another accommodation like: Separate Setting, Extended Time, or English as a Second Language (ESL) then they are welcome in the lab as long as the lab is not full.  If the lab reaches capacity and Read-Aloud students need to use Kurzweil, the student(s) without a Read-Aloud accommodation or who are refusing their Read-Aloud accommodation will be asked to go back to their classroom so that the teacher can make other arrangements for that student.</p>' + 
                        '<p>During non-testing situations the Kurzweil Lab can be scheduled by EC teachers to help with study skills, individual projects, or other work that requires the use of a computer lab.</p>', true);
}

function calendar(app){
  // Create Data Source
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dGJIOGZ1LXhqT2FNMGVXSGNJazFnUmc');
  var datasource = ss.getSheetByName('Schedule').getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn());

  // Create Charts and Controls
  var dateFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Date").build();
  var teacherFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Teacher").build();
  var subjectFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Subject").build();
  var periodFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Period").build();
  var typeFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Type").build();
  var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart().build();

  //Create and bind Dashboard
  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
      .setDataTable(datasource)
      .bind([dateFilter, teacherFilter, subjectFilter, periodFilter, typeFilter], [tableChart])
      .build();

  //Create Application
  dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel()
                .add(app.createHorizontalPanel()
                     .add(dateFilter).add(teacherFilter).add(subjectFilter).add(periodFilter).add(typeFilter)
                     .setSpacing(70))
                .add(app.createHorizontalPanel()
                     .add(tableChart)
                     .setSpacing(10)));

  //Add the panel to the application
  app.add(dashboard);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot that you changed the way every function that build the UI returns data... If you remember [your first post about stackPanels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255135/add-apps-to-stackpanel) we changed the call to

```
  var cal = calendar(app);
```

and then

```
  var p2 = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vrtPanel2').add(cal);
```

So we clearly expect to get a Ui object (a widget) in return.

You can simply change the end of the `function calendar(app){` like below :

```
  ...
  dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel()
                .add(app.createHorizontalPanel()
                     .add(dateFilter).add(teacherFilter).add(subjectFilter).add(periodFilter).add(typeFilter)
                     .setSpacing(70))
                .add(app.createHorizontalPanel()
                     .add(tableChart)
                     .setSpacing(10)));

  //Add the panel to the application
  return dashboard;// return the dashboard itself, not the app.
}
```

---

EDIT : this was definitely to simple to be true... my answer was correct but obviously didn't include the issues with the dashboard building.

After a few researches (I've never used Charts service before) I came to this code that produces no errors but I'm definitely not sure it returns what you wanted...

Nevertheless it should help you to find your way. (don't blame me if it doesn't look right ;-)

```
function calendar(app){
  // Create Data Source
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dGJIOGZ1LXhqT2FNMGVXSGNJazFnUmc');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Schedule');
  var datasource = sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(datasource)
  var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable();
  for( var j in datasource[0] ){
  dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, datasource[0][j]);
  }
  for( var i = 1; i < datasource.length; ++i ){
  dataTable.addRow(datasource[i].map(String));
  }
var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(dataTable);  // Create Charts and Controls
  var dateFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Date").setDataTable(dataTable).build();
  var teacherFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Teacher").setDataTable(dataTable).build();
  var subjectFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Subject").setDataTable(dataTable).build();
  var periodFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Period").setDataTable(dataTable).build();
  var typeFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Type").setDataTable(dataTable).build();
  var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart().setDimensions(1000, 600).setDataTable(dataTable).build();

  //Create and bind Dashboard
  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
      .setDataTable(dataTable)
      .bind([dateFilter, teacherFilter, subjectFilter, periodFilter, typeFilter], [tableChart])
      .build();

  //Create Application
  var dashBoardPanel = app.createVerticalPanel()
  dashBoardPanel.add(app.createHorizontalPanel()
                     .add(dateFilter).add(teacherFilter).add(subjectFilter).add(periodFilter).add(typeFilter)
                     .setSpacing(30));
  dashBoardPanel.add(tableChart);

  //Add the panel to the application
  return dashBoardPanel;
}
```

---

**EDIT 2** : to get the first column as a date you have to slightly modify the `for loops` that populate the `dataTables` so that you can convert to string only from the second column.

I did it like this :

```
function calendar(app){
      // Create Data Source
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dGJIOGZ1LXhqT2FNMGVXSGNJazFnUmc');
      var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Schedule');
      var datasource = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      Logger.log(datasource)
      var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable();
      dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.DATE, datasource[0][1]);
      for( var j=2 ;j< datasource[0].length ;++j ){
        dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, datasource[0][j]);
      }
      for( var i = 1; i < datasource.length; ++i ){
        var datarow = [];
        datarow.push(datasource[i][1]);
        for( var j=2 ;j< datasource[0].length ;++j ){
          datarow.push(datasource[i][j].toString());
        }
        dataTable.addRow(datarow);
      }
         var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(dataTable);  // Create Charts and Controls
          ...
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting "Object type does not match column type." How can I return all the data in my dynamic spreadsheet?

Comment: I cannot test further because I don't have access to your SS, it is probably the filter function that expect some other type of data or the charts itself... maybe you could explain/show some data ?  Couldn't open document with id 0Aur3owCpuUY-dGJIOGZ1LXhqT2FNMGVXSGNJazFnUmc: You do not have permissions to access the requested document.

Comment: You should be able to access it now... if not let me know and I'll try something else.

Comment: answer updated... but I'm really a newbie in Charts service... sorry . maybe you could ask some help on how to get the right type of dashboard in a separate thread as the issue is not on adding it to a stackPanel anymore but about charts service features.

Comment: No blaming, glad for the help. Just figured I missed something simple or was doing something incorrect. I will take this to a new thread and see what happens if this doesn't give the results I want and I can't figure it out from here. I just thought this would be better than the calendar option...

Comment: Did you try this version ?  Was it something like that you where thinking of?

Comment: I did and it works great... the only issue is I am trying to set the first column to a DATE instead of a STRING.

Comment: I updated the code to have the first column in your table to be dates

Comment: It's not working... I'm getting a "Object type does not match column type."

Comment: Did you update var data source =...  too?  I changed this definition too

Comment: I copied/pasted it to replace the upper part of the code... what should I change or do different.

Comment: Thanks... got it working. I thought I would have to modify the for loop just wasn't sure how.

Comment: great, I'll remove the link and sharing to avoid spammers ;-) PS : there was indeed a typo in the code... don't know how it's even possible since I copy/pasted it but there was a [3] instead of [1]... weird...

Comment: The filter functions were not working in this code... when I change this line of code it works : `dashBoardPanel.add(tableChart).add(dashboard);`